# in java multi-catch every multi-catch character is final, but I'm not able to get it

Tags: java, exception

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        try{
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("yyyoyo");
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException |ArithmeticException e)
        {
            e.initCause(new Exception());
        }
    }
}
```

As we know that multi-catch parameter is implicitly final, so how I'm able to chain an exception in the catch block.

Comment: @NathanHughes I got what you said, but can you give me an example, where there will be an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `final` reference means you can not assign a new value to it. It does not stop the object from being updated.

For example:

```
class MyClass {
    String string;

    public MyClass(String string) {
        super();
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass [string=" + string + "]";
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyClass obj = new MyClass("Test");
        System.out.println(obj);
        obj.setString("Testing");
        System.out.println(obj);

        // obj= new MyClass("Testing"); // Trying to assign a new value to obj will result in a compilation error
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
MyClass [string=Test]
MyClass [string=Testing]
```

Comment: I need an example corresponding to the stated code, where I'll break the law of final variable and get an error related to the same.